# How can I stream logs from a cloud run service to my terminal?

Tags: google-cloud-run

Is it possible to stream logs from my Cloud Run service into my terminal? I have found a query that works using `gcloud logging read ...` but it takes about 20 seconds to run and it exits after printing the current logs, whereas what I want is to keep watching for new logs and printing them.

My service is only being used by me at present so it generates very few logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gcloud beta run services logs tail SERVICE_NAME` https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/logging#viewing-logs-gcloud